# Divide dataframe column by a specific cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to divide a dataframe column by a specific cell in the same dataframe.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 date      type          score   
 20201101  experiment1   30      
 20201101  experiment2   20      
 20201101  baseline      10      
 20201102  experiment1   60      
 20201102  experiment2   50      
 20201102  baseline      10
```

I want to compute the score_ratio by dividing the score by the 'baseline' score of that date.

```
 date      type          score   score_ratio
 20201101  experiment1   30      3
 20201101  experiment2   20      2
 20201101  baseline      10      1
 20201102  experiment1   60      6
 20201102  experiment2   50      5
 20201102  baseline      10      1
```

The score_ratio for `(date, type) = (20201101, experiment1)` should be obtained by dividing its score by the score of `(20201101, baseline)`. In this case, it should be 30 / 10 = 3. Similarly. for `(20201101, experiment2)`, we should divide the score by the same thing, `(20201101, baseline)`. For a different date, say `(20201102, experiment1)`, it should be divided by the baseline of that date, `(20201102, baseline)`.

How do I add this column with dataframe operations?

So far, I have this but am unsure of what expression I should be dividing by:  `df['score_ratio'] = df['score'].div(...)`

Edit:

I get the error for the last line
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

```
     ID    date        type          room    score         
0  id1     20201120    baseline      1     450.25    
0  id2     20201120    experiment1   1     -3637.24   
0  id3     20201121    baseline      1     200.00   
1  id4     20201121    experiment1   1     300.00   
2  id5     20201120    baseline      2     600.00   
3  id6     20201120    experiment1   2     800.00   


    _df = df.set_index('date', 'room')
    d = _df.query('type=="baseline"')
    print(_df['score'].div(d['score']).values)
    df['score_ratio'] = _df['score'].div(d['score']).values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #Mask all whose type is baseline into a new datframe and merge to the main df
 g=pd.merge(df, df[df.type.eq('baseline')].drop(columns='type'),how='left', on='date', suffixes=('', '_right'))

 #Calculate the score_ratio and drop the extra column acquired during merge
    df=g.assign(score_ratio=g.score.div(g.score_right).astype(int)).drop(columns=['score_right'])

print(df)

     date         type  score    score_ratio
0  20201101  experiment1     30            3
1  20201101  experiment2     20            2
2  20201101     baseline     10            1
3  20201102  experiment1     60            6
4  20201102  experiment2     50            5
5  20201102     baseline     10            1
```

**How it works**

```
#New dataframe with baselines only
df1=df[df.type.eq('baseline')].drop(columns='type')

#Modified original dataframe with baselines added
g=pd.merge(df, df1,how='left', on='date', suffixes=('', '_right'))

#new column called score_ratio
g=g.assign(score_ratio=g.score.div(g.score_right).astype(int))

#drop column called score_right which was acquired during merge
g=g.drop(columns=['score_right'])
```

Comment: Can you explain? Look cool but i want to inderstand too

Comment: @adir abargil  see my edits on how it works for step by step approach

Comment: Im not the question owner, but ofc i voted you

Answer (score 0):

You set `date` column as index, then filter out where `type` is `baseline` then use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html)

```
_df = df.set_index('date')
d = _df.query('type=="baseline"') # same as _df.loc[_df['type'].eq('baseline')]
df['score_ratio'] = _df['score'].div(d['score']).values
df
       date         type  score  score_ratio
0  20201101  experiment1     30          3.0
1  20201101  experiment2     20          2.0
2  20201101     baseline     10          1.0
3  20201102  experiment1     60          6.0
4  20201102  experiment2     50          5.0
5  20201102     baseline     10          1.0
```

Comment: Hi, I added an edit to my question showing the error when I tried doing this. The dataframe shown in the edit is more representative of my actual data. Can you take a look and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `df.set_index('date', 'room')` change this to `df.set_index('date')` @1step1leap

Answer (score 0):

in just 3 simple lines of code and commented:

```
# set index to ['date', 'type']
df.set_index(['date', 'type'], inplace=True)

# helper: values of score at index 'baseline'
s = df.xs('baseline', level=1)  

# divide df by series and reset index
df.div(s, level=0).reset_index()


      date         type  score
0  20201101  experiment1    3.0
1  20201101  experiment2    2.0
2  20201101     baseline    1.0
3  20201102  experiment1    6.0
4  20201102  experiment2    5.0
5  20201102     baseline    1.0
```